# What is the proper way to use a .equals method in Java?

Tags: java, coding-style

I was talking with my CompSci professor and he suggested that all String `.equals` methods be written as:

```
"Hello World".equals(fooString);
```

rather than:

```
fooString.equals("Hello World");
```

Both of these lines compile, but I was wondering what are the benefits of the first way?  I've always done it the latter way.  Is this wrong? What is common/conventional?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first way ensures that you will not receive a **NullPointerException** when you perform the comparison.  This Exception is thrown (occurs) when you try to invoke a method on an object that doesn't exist.

*Somewhat Relevant Tangent Below: Peruse At Own Risk*

As a note, though, I have very, very rarely actually seen this technique or coding style used in a legitimate production environment.  There are two reasons for this.

First, programs you write will almost always want to do something special or different in the case that your variable contains **null**.  This is because it usually indicates an error in some other part of the code's function or a special case that needs to be addressed.  As such, null checking should always occur *before* any comparisons or method calls on the object (in this case, your `String fooString`).

Second, `fooString.equals("Hello World")` just tends to make your code slightly more readable.  The logical significance of the first technique in your code takes a few seconds to process correctly, and it is easy to make an error of judgment when you are skimming over hundreds or thousands of lines of code.  This is actually much less trivial than it sounds, because in the working world, more often than not, there are very large and very old programs that will be patched by people who knew nothing about them before glancing at them to solve the problem.  Code readability contributes in a huge way to a company's ability to perform fast triage and solve long term problems.

Comment: long story short: the first is typical form-over-function thinking of compsci academics who never wrote a single line of production code in their life :)

Comment: .. because a boatload of `nvl()` equivalent calls makes it any easier to read?

Comment: I rarely see `nvl()` in my production code, either, but then again my company uses more Teradata and DB2. :)

Comment: My comment was directed at Philipp but our Oracle db guys love nvl.  Hurts my eyes.

Answer (score 18):

The first way guarantees `NullPointerException` is never thrown, while the second one may risk getting `NullPointerException` if the `fooString` happens to be `null`.

However, in the end, it all boils down to the requirement. If the requirement specifies that the `null` case should not happen at all, or should be treated differently, then writing in the 2nd way (`fooString.equals()`) helps you detect the implementation flaw. If you can treat `null` as just another case, then the 1st way is fine.

Comment: There is no such thing random NullPointerException. This exception is thrown only when one or more of cases defined by this spec occur  (no randomness here) i wonder how this got 14 upvotes. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html

Comment: @aviad: I admit "random" is not a good choice of word here. I wrote it with the meaning of forgetting to check for `null` before de-referencing, and getting the NullPointerException at some time later.