# Java - Coding Style : What are the cons and pros of "ABC".equals("SOMESTRING") style string comparison?

Tags: java, string

Let me first start-of with a sample code...

```
String password = "";

if("PIRATE".equals(password)) {
     // Do something
}
```

See here, the *String constant or literal* (whatever) "PIRATE" is used to check the equality of the two Strings. Whereas...

```
String password = "";
if(password.equals("PIRATE")) {
     // Do something
}
```

this also works exactly as the previous code.

Now-a-days, I see a lot of the first style **"STRING_LITERAL".equals(STRING_OBJECT)**, while Java people post code.

So my question is, **Where does this style comes from ?** and **Is it better than the second style in any way ?**

In-fact i find the second style more logical than the first one, why ?!

lets take a requirement like, *if the user-provided-password is equal to the "PIRATE" then give permission to that user*

when you start implementing the above requirement,

```
String userProvidedPassword = getPaswordFromUser();

if(userProvidedPassword.equals("PIRATE")) {
 // Allow him
}
```

Doesn't this more logical than **"PIRATE".equals(userProvidedPassword);** ?! Just think about it...

Correct me if I'm wrong.. Thanks..

---

EDIT : Sorry, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12486977/1655217) didn't come up in my previous search, and it answers my question perfectly. Also thanks to all those who helped out here..

Comment: You avoid an explicit null-check.  This makes for more concise code.

Comment: With this : `userProvidedPassword.equals("PIRATE")` you need an extra null check : `userProvidedPassword!=null && userProvidedPassword.equals("PIRATE")`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you write `password.equals("PIRATE")` you are almost asking for a `NullPointerException` ,where there are chances for `password`  might `null.`

It's all about Avoiding `NullPointerException`.

```
if("PIRATE".equals(password)) {
     // Do something
}
```

Avoids `NullPointerException`

where as

```
if(password.equals("PIRATE")) {
     // Do something
}
```

thrwos you  `NullPointerException`  if `password` is `null`.

However ,Personally I feel this is looks odd in middle of the code. and I always prefer to write

```
if(password !=null && password.equals("PIRATE") ){

//do something 

}
```

Comment: Great answer, good job.

Comment: thanks suresh.. that explains..

Comment: @Dreamer Glad,I could help you :)

Answer (score 17):

`"PIRATE".equals(password)` cannot result in a `NullPointerException`.

whereas

`password.equals("PIRATE")` will throw a `NullPointerException` if `password` happens to be `null`.

Therefore the use of the former is encouraged : it is safer.

Comment: Great answer, I'd never realized this before. Hindsight is 20/20, seems obvious now!

Comment: excellent.. thanks.. i too didn't think in that way.. by the way what can be done about the **string hardcoding** issue while using this style ?

Comment: Use a constant instead of the hardcoded String

Comment: I would'nt say that the use of the former is encouraged. It is a nice way to prevent null pointers but most people find it unintuitive to read. What I would encourage is using the latter one and program in a way that the string variable can't be `null`.

Answer (score 3):

The only con is really a style problem. Saying "PIRATE".equals(password) is called a [Yoda Condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_Conditions). However, as people have already stated, it is safer to use that kind of condition (so I would keep using that kind).

Comment: +1 For mentioning the Yoda condition !