# Using negation of equals method

Tags: java, while-loop, nullpointerexception, equals

I'm trying to set up a while loop as follows:

```
while(!data.equals("String");
```

Whenever I run this code, I get a NullPointerException.
Why is this?

If I change the code to:

```
while(data.equals("String");
```

I get no such exception, so there must be data in data, correct?

EDIT:  Adding real code at the behest of commentors.

The following code is a method that attempts to convert infix notation into postfix notation.

```
    public static Queue infixConvert (LinkedListTest infix){
    Stack stack = new Stack();
    Queue postfix = new Queue();

    while(infix.head.data != "EOF"){

        if(isNumber(infix.head.data)){
            postfix.insert(infix.head.data);
            System.out.println("Insert Queue");
            System.out.println("Operator");
        }

        else if (infix.head.data.equals("(") || infix.head.data.equals(")")){
            if(("(").equals(infix.head.data)){
                stack.push(infix.head.data);
                System.out.println("Open paren");
            }
            else {
                infix.delete(")");
                while(!"(".equals(stack.head.data)){
                    stack.delete(")");
                    postfix.insert(stack.pop());
                    System.out.println("Insert Queue");
                }
                stack.delete("(");
                System.out.println("Close Paren");
            }
        }

        else{
            if(!(highPrec(stack.head.data, infix.head.data))){
                stack.push(infix.head.data);
                System.out.println("Push onto Lesser Operand");
            }

            else if(highPrec(stack.head.data, infix.head.data)){
                while(stack.head.data != null){
                    if (stack.head.data != "("){
                        postfix.insert(stack.pop());
                    }
                    else break;
                }
                stack.push(infix.head.data);
                System.out.println("Push onto Greater Operand");
            }

            if (infix.head.data == "EOL"){
                while(stack.head.data != "EOL"){
                postfix.insert(stack.pop());
                System.out.println("End Line");
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(infix.head.data);
        infix.head = infix.head.next;
        System.out.println("loop\n");
    }
    return postfix;
}
}
```

EDIT: Added stack trace

```
 at Calculator.infixConvert(Calculator.java:57) 
 at Test.main(Test.java:7)
```

Comment: neither `while(!data.equals("String");` nor `while(data.equals("String");` are valid Java... Can you add some context to your question?

Comment: Not possible (as you described it). Are you sure that the NPE is not thrown in your while and in the first case the condition is evaluated to true?

Comment: The others are right, something else is going on here. Post a bit more of your code, the exception including stack trace, and say which line of your code corresponds to which line in the stack trace.

Comment: Post real code please.

Comment: @tim_yates

The while loop is supposed to check the data in a stack and pop all the data until it sees a certain string.  data would be stack.head.data (the head of the linkedlist which I have extended stack off of).

Comment: @ZouZou Elaborate please.  I assume it's in my while, because the line reference for the error corresponds to the line at which I instantiated the while loop.

Comment: Are you getting the NPE before the loop starts running or during the loop? If the latter, what's the full loop code?

Comment: If you're getting a null pointer, provide the code you are running and the stack trace.

Answer (score 6):

You could do it **["Yoda-style"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486977/what-is-the-proper-way-to-use-a-equals-method-in-java)**:

```
while(!"String".equals(data)) {
     //writing code here you must!
}
```

because for the case `data` is null then it would not cause NPE because you call equals method of the "String"

Comment: `;` is not necessary.

Comment: This prevents NPEs if `data` is null. However, if it WAS null, `while(data.equals("String");` wouldn't work either, but it does according to the OP. still, +1.

Comment: I already tried this, I get the same NPE

Comment: @ChristianBaker Then this is not this line which throws this.

Comment: agree with @ZouZou here

Comment: +1 this is a common, standard idiom for comparing `String`s that may be `null` to string literals.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but I have tried this fix.  I have faced this problem before, and when this did not solve the issue, I was confounded.

Comment: @ChristianBaker no problem. I do think the root cause of your problem is in another line then. Can you please post full stacktrace and the relevant code please?

Comment: @Christian yep you are right :-) removed `;` for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue.

There was some other unintentional behavior that caused the "(" String to be removed from the stack, so when the while loop ran it would run through the entire stack until it hit null, and provided me with a NPE.